# Let $G$ be a group of order $72$. Show that if $G$ is not cyclic, then for any $g \in G$ either $g^{24} = 1$ or $g^{36} = 1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I have the following problem and could not understand why there are just two cases.

> **Problem:** Let $G$ be a group of order $72$. Show that if $G$ is not cyclic, then for any $g \in G$ either $g^{24} = 1$ or $g^{36} = 1$

I know that the order of an element in a group divides the order of the group, and $g^{72} = 1$ cannot be the case because $G$ is not cyclic but, for example, why are we not considering of $g^{12} = 1$ case?

I would be appreciated if anyone help me.

Regards.

Comment: You are confused. You wrote $g^{72}=1$ cannot be the case, but that is wrong, $g^{72}=1$ for all $g \in G$. It is possible that $g^{12}=1$, but in that case $g^{24}=g^{36}=1$, and the result is true. You are asked to prove that for all $g$ either $g^{24}=1$ or $g^{36}=1$. Think about it some more.

Comment: **Hint :** Show that all the proper divisors of $72$ divide either $24$, and $36$, and try to understand why this implies the statement.

Comment: In case comment by @DerekHolt may not appear as sensible to you, recall that order of an element $g$ is the *smallest* integer $n$ such that $g^n=1$ while the assertion either $g^{24}=1$ or $g^{36}=1$ in the problem above *do not necessarily* imply the order of g is either 24 or 36.

Comment: It is much more clear for me now thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g\in G$.

Since $|G|=72$, we must have, by Lagrange's Theorem, that $|g|$ divides $72$.

But $G$ is not cyclic, so the *order* of $g$ cannot be $72$ (despite the fact that $g^{72}=1$).

Therefore,

$$|g|\in\{ 1,2,3,6,8,9,12,18,24,36\}.$$

The result follows; for example, if $|g|=9$, then $g^9=1$ implies $g^{36}=(g^9)^{4}=1^{4}=1$.

Comment: Thank you! @Shaun

Comment: You're welcome, @yeyosef!